# Elasticsearch 6.0 and Raspberry pi 3

Tags: elasticsearch, raspberry-pi, cpu, raspbian, raspberry-pi3

has anyone expersience with Elasticsearch on Raspberry pi.
I  installed today the new version of ES 6.0 on Raspberry pi 3 and i have the problem that every time when i open Internet explorer to check ES Localhost then all the system will blocked. 100% CPU.

how can i figure it out ?
Thanks in advance

Comment: By default ES starts with 2GB of heap, maybe you need to change that settings in the `config/jvm.options` file to something that your Pi can handle.

Comment: i tried  Xms and XMM with 512 and with 256 as well, but Raspberry is still slowly